How to make sure to only get full frame lenses for the Canon EF (non-mirrorless) mount?
As an amateur, I am looking for used lenses for my Canon EOS 5D Mark II. I know that it's so called full frame, like the old 35mm film cameras. I am confused with all the abbreviations and possibilities for lenses.
When reading about mounts, I learn that EF-S was specifically designed for the smaller APS-C sensor. So, I should avoid lenses that are made specifically for these.
Is it enough to

avoid "EF-S" lenses and only get "EF" lenses?
avoid Sigma "DC DN" and only get "DG DN" (Canon mount only, but they are marketed for mirror-less which my DSLR is not)


Definitely worth reading: What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?

The question, What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?, and its answers cover this. But in summary, for your question:
Canon lenses
Only consider EF lenses. As you said, EF-S lenses are ~1.6 crop image circle lenses. EF-M lenses are for Canon's mirrorless bodies, and won't even mount on your camera.
Sigma lenses
You're looking for Canon-mount, DG lenses. If it says DN, it won't mount on your camera.
Tamron lenses
Di lenses. Di II are for crop-sensors, and Di III are for mirrorless cameras.
Nikon lenses
The option exists for Canon EF body owners to mount most old-school Nikon F-mount lenses, using a F-to-ES (Nikon-to-Canon) mount adapter. Older Nikon lenses will have manual focus and aperture controls, and will work fine adapted to your Canon body. If there is no "FX" or "DX" designation, it will likely work. 'DX' is a crop image circle lens, so stay away from those. FX is full-frame. Many FX lenses will 'work' on a Canon body, but depending on the quality of the lens adapter, it might not pass communications to the lens; especially if the lens has a G designation (which requires the adapter to physically control the Nikon lens's aperture). Also, make sure the lens has its own motor, not relying on the camera body to have a motor; AF-S and AF-P Nikon lenses will work on your Canon body.

Even worse about EF-M is that they are for Canon's abandoned, crop-only, mirrorless system that they never seemed to give a damn about.  Not that physics will allow you to mount any mirrorless lens to an SLR without extra elements and maintain infinity focus.

Very insightful, especially intersting to me is the Nikon part since I actually own some older manual focus Nikon lenses. I will read up about such adapters, but wonder about the focal lenghts of those, with the adapter in between.

@Marcel: Focal length is the same (search for "flange focal distance"). You might want an adapter with a "Dandelion" or "AF confirm" chip for Canon.

@Marcel Mounting lens with a longer flange registration depth (like Nikon lenses) on bodies with shorter flange registration depths (like Canon bodies) doesn't involve adding any optics to the adapters; they're empty air, essentially just the correct length "spacer" (and correct mount/bayonet interfaces, of course). That's why mounting SLR lenses onto mirrorless bodies doesn't require additional optics, and therefore doesn't change the effective focal length of the lens system.

@davolfman The EOS M system was the world's best selling interchangeable lens mirrorless camera system for years. Canon created it for a market that most "shutterbugs" are not a part of. It was never meant for enthusiasts or others who want to constantly "upgrade" their "arsenal". It was for folks who wanted a relatively small, lightweight, and affordable ILC and 1-3 lenses that they could use for the next few years w/out worrying about what might else be introduced over that time span. There were a LOT more of them than "us" until smartphone improvements took most of that market.

It is not enough to avoid EF-S lenses because third-party manufacturers (at least Sigma) make APS-C lenses with EF mounts. If you're looking at Canon lenses, then this is enough, but not if you're looking at third-party lenses.
Usually there will be, in the marketing material or in reviews or on comparison websites, an explicit statement whether any lens is full-frame compatible. For example Sigma's own description of their 18-35 1.8 says in big letters that it is an "APS-C format standard zoom lens" and further down you'll also find this information next to the words "Sensor Format"; meanwhile the 24-70 2.8 has the words "Full-frame" in the same location.

In Sigma's case, that's what "DC" vs. "DG" distinguishes: DG is for full-frame, DC is APS-C crop.
